# Reactjs Sidebar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My sidebar data is not showing on the screen. I have the sidebar data and I am mapping the data from sidebar.js but it does not display the information on the browser. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import ComputerIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Computer";
export const SidebarData = [
{
  title: "Home",
  icon: <HomeIcon />,
  link: "/home",
},
{
  title: "Computer Support",
  icon: <ComputerIcon />,
  link: "/computer",
},
]
```

The code for my sidebar.js is as follows

```
import { SidebarData } from "./SidebarData";

 function Sidebar() {
   return (
     <div className="Sidebar">
       <ul>
         {SidebarData.map((val, key) => {
           return (
             <li
               key={key}
               onClick={() => {
                 window.location.pathname = val.link;
               }}
             >
               <div>{val.icon}</div> <div>{val.title}</div>
             </li>
           );
         })}
       </ul>
    </div>
   );
 }

 export default Sidebar;
```

here is my App.js code

```
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar";

 function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <Sidebar />
     </div>
   );
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: looks fine in here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bkrajw?file=App.tsx

Comment: Have you tried setting the sidebar a different colour or giving it width and height properties, to see if the div itself is rendering?

Comment: @Sachila Ranawaka No error in the console.

Comment: @GazWinter I made sure the div is rendering before adding the sidebar data.

Comment: Strange. What do you get if you console.log(SidebarData)?

Comment: @GazWinter, the problem was with Material UI v5, it does not work with react v18. I will have to downgrade to react v17 or v16.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it  helps

```
import * as React from "react";

import {
  Box,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  Drawer
} from "@material-ui/core";

const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: "Home",
    icon: <HomeIcon />,
    link: "/home"
  },
  {
    title: "Computer Support",
    icon: <ComputerIcon />,
    link: "/computer"
  }
];

const sideList = () => (
  <Box>
    {SidebarData.map((listItem, index) => (
      <ListItem button key={index}>
        <ListItemIcon>{listItem.icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={listItem.title}  onClick={() => {
             window.location.pathname = listItem.link;
           }} />
      </ListItem>
    ))}
  </Box>
);

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Sidebar">
      <button onClick={handleToggle}>show</button>

      <Drawer open={open} anchor="right" onClick={handleToggle}>
        {sideList()}
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Whilst these suggestions are valid, they could try and use the different MUI elements. That might not be the intention and therefore it should work as the user originally posted.